# Почему фразеологизм « как зеницу ока» обычно не обособляют?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

***Беречь как зеницу ока.***

```
Учебный фразеологический словарь: ***как зеницу 
ока.*** Неизм. Бдительно, очень заботливо. Чаще с 
глаг. несов. вида: беречь, хранить… как? как зеницу 
ока.
```

1. Это известный фразеологизм, который в текстах обычно не обособляется, **а почему?** Только из-за того, что это **фразеологизм?** Неужели это особая **привилегия** для устойчивых оборотов?
2. Но примеры **с обособлением** в Нацкорпусе тоже встречаются, вот один из них:

*Этот хребет мы будем **беречь, **как зеницу ока**.**..*(2001 г.). Ошибка автора?

А если так: *Этот хребет мы **беречь будем,  как зеницу ока**...* Тоже ошибка?

3. **И вопрос:** как объяснить **отсутствие** обособления для этого фразеологизма в большинстве текстов?

**[Статья](https://dzen.ru/a/YQlO9hKwV3BQHw6h):** **Что означают выражения «Беречь как зеницу ока» и слово «Зеница»?**

Comment: Ср.: _«Почему фразеологизм « как зеницу ока» **обычно обособляют**?», «Это известный фразеологизм, который в текстах **обычно не обособляется**»_.  ❓

Comment: Он обычно не обособляется и его не обособляют, специально проверяла. Спасибо)

Comment: Объяснительная записка. У меня сложные отношения с частицей НЕ. Я мыслю образами-картинками  и вижу обособленный оборот. Словами его надо отрицать, но картинка сильнее слов, так что НЕ иногда пропадает.  На уровне подсознания НЕ не воспринимается, у словечка энергетика никакая)